# bootstrap, button above footer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i wanted to put 2 buttons just above the navbar (see the link as below)
http://postimg.org/image/o0dga8wux/

i62.tinypic.com/2r7lc2g.png

this is my code:

```
<form id="form1"  runat="server">
        <div>some content</div>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom" role="navigation">            
            <div class="container">
                <div class="container-fluid" style="color:white">
                    footer
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
</form>
```

---------------UPDATE WITH FIDDLE------------------

fiddle: http://www.bootply.com/122652

Comment: image is not showing. Can you show us your css so we don't insult your intelligence by suggesting things you might have already tried? :)

correction: I know it's bootstrap, but I mean you r particular css code to achieve what you are trying to achieve

Comment: sorry, i checked the link, it working fine here. however, i added a new link, please check :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, please reference the official documentation on buttons [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons).

You could do it like this:

```
<form id="form1"  runat="server">
        <div>some content</div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Default</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom" role="navigation">            
            <div class="container">
                <div class="container-fluid" style="color:white">
                    footer
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
</form>
```

Comment: sorry, may be i din't made myself clear, i wanted 2 buttons stick JUST ABOVE the footer. please see the link i attached at the question :)

Answer (score -1):

Here you go.

```
.buttons {
   position: relative;
   top: 0px;
   left: 410px;
}
```

Use this link http://jsfiddle.net/4JAwZ/1/
    [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4JAwZ/4/)

Comment: thank you, but i don't think it's a good solution. we cannot expect all the user using the same screen resolution.

Comment: i update my question with fiddle. however, still not perfect. the footer will overlap the button if the screen resolution is too small.

Comment: The fiddle works as you need it now. I didn't include the width of the wrapper that would set the parameters for the page boundaries. I thought you'd figured that part out since every page must gave some width defined to ensure everything can be aligned. Hope it works for you now